# Converting multiple JFrames into one single JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, layout-manager

As the title suggests, I have to find a way to convert multiple JFrames that are connected to each other (they are all in the same package by the way) into a single JApplet. I know that I should have used jPanels instead of jFrames, but I have already more than 10 jFrames and I found nothing online(They are all about converting a single frame to a japplet)

What I tried so far is that I initialized ProgramEntrance (which is the beginning JFrame of the whole program) into the applet's init() method. But it didn't work. So I am in a desperate situation, any helps or comments will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the 10 frames to 10 panels.  Add the 10 panels to 1 panel with a `CardLayout`.  Add the 1 panel to:

1. A `JFrame` to be launched from a a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).
2. A `JApplet` embedded in a web page.

### BTW

1. What *is* your question?
2. Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question was whether I am able to convert a java application to an applet so as to put in a web page. And after hours of research, I realized that converting  to an applet is the only option. Thanks for the explanation again, but I didn't understand the first statement. Why do I have to use JWS? And I forgot to tell that I also have JInternalFrames and JDesktopPane in the program, and sometimes when you click on a button, a new panel appears (the old one doesn't disappear) on the screen and asks for some input. Do I have to convert all these frames to panels?

Comment: The 1st group of 1)/2) are alternatives.  The 1st being better for the users.  You can put a desktop pane in a (card layout in a) panel.  You can put it wherever it needs to be.